# How do I get a full list of datasets available on Data.Gov using the CKAN API?

Tags: data.gov, ckan

I'm fairly new to python, but I've been struggling to get anything more than ten results from a package_list request from Data.Gov's CKAN API.  Here's what I'm using:

```
response = urlopen('http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/action/package_list')
assert response.code == 200

response_dict = json.loads(response.read())

assert response_dict['success'] is True
len(response_dict['result']['results'])
```

The result is only 10 datasets.  This is the same when I use package_search, it only returns the first ten results.  What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find the answer in the CKAN documentation.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated!

- Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For now the Data.gov CKAN API redirects `package_list` to `package_search` and for `package_search` [the relevant Solr parameters to limit your query are `rows` and `start`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search).

For example, `http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/action/package_search?rows=1000&start=0`

And then page through.

If you or anyone has additional feedback on what Data.gov CKAN API documentation would be helpful or would like to help contribute there is [a relevant issue](https://github.com/GSA/data.gov/issues/180) open on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I see that now, when I just put that into my browser.  I think it might be giving me the right number of results, but I'm having a hard time parsing the data it returns.  Any suggestions there?

Answer (score 1):

The [API documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.2/api.html) lists two arguments to package_list :

> Parameters:
>
> - limit (int) – if given, the list of datasets will be broken into pages of at most `limit` datasets per page and only one page will be returned at a time (optional)
> - offset (int) – when `limit` is given, the offset to start returning packages from

They don't mention if they count from 1 or from 0 ... but I'd suggest trying increasing `limit` sizes (100, 1000, 5000, etc.) until they stop returning that many, and then send an `offset` of the number they gave you, and see if they still give you more, then keep adding `limit` to the `offset` value until they don't give you anything.

Comment: The problem is that package_list currently does not work at data.gov :)

Comment: @Sicco : yeah, I gathered that from Rebecca's response.  I'm going to leave my answer here incase they every allow it through again, and then I'll have the rght answer.