# Extract all data from ckan

Tags: ckan

I'm trying to export all data from CKAN instances for a big data project.
How can I do this?

Comment: and how can i get all of its data ?

Comment: What do you mean all of its data? Do you have access to that CKAN instance? Do you want only the files or you also want the metadata?

Comment: @AlexPalcuie, the metadata, the csv and xml files as well

Comment: all data from every ckan instance, or all from one instance? if its one instance, which is it? @ojdo's answer is pretty informative

Comment: also some harvesters are in here: https://github.com/opendatamonitor/

Answer (score 4):

Did you have a look at CKAN's extensive [API documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html)? To get you started, look at the answer to related question [How do I get a full list of datasets available on Data.Gov using the CKAN API?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4240/930) and its example of using [`package_search`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.get.package_search).

Once you have a list of dataset IDs, you can get their metadata using the [`package_show`](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.get.package_show) API function.

The package `url` field sometimes contains directly downloadable files, sometimes they seem link to data provider pages which might need some individual handling (i.e. coding). But only restricting batch download to recognised filetypes (e.g. `*.csv`) should get you pretty far already.